# Passing commands in string to CMD.exe goes wrong

Tags: c#

I found a solution (code below) to pass **many commands**  to **CMD.exe**. But the **value** is wrong **in cmdStr** variable. **CMD.exe** executes but it shows the following message:

> 'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

```
/// <span class="code-SummaryComment"><summary></span>
/// Executes a shell command synchronously.
/// <span class="code-SummaryComment"></summary></span>
/// <span class="code-SummaryComment"><param name="command">string command</param></span>
/// <span class="code-SummaryComment"><returns>string, as output of the command.</returns></span>
public void ExecuteCommandSync(object command)
{
    try
    {
        // create the ProcessStartInfo using "cmd" as the program to be run,
        // and "/c " as the parameters.
        // Incidentally, /c tells cmd that we want it to execute the command that follows,
        // and then exit.
        System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo =
            new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("cmd", "/k " + command);

        // The following commands are needed to redirect the standard output.
        // This means that it will be redirected to the Process.StandardOutput StreamReader.
        procStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        procStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        // Do not create the black window.
        procStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
        // Now we create a process, assign its ProcessStartInfo and start it
        System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        proc.StartInfo = procStartInfo;
        proc.Start();
        // Get the output into a string
        string result = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        // Display the command output.
        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }
    catch (Exception objException)
    {
        // Log the exception
    }
}

/// <span class="code-SummaryComment"><summary></span>
/// Execute the command Asynchronously.
/// <span class="code-SummaryComment"></summary></span>
/// <span class="code-SummaryComment"><param name="command">string command.</param></span>
public void ExecuteCommandAsync(string command)
{
    try
    {
        //Asynchronously start the Thread to process the Execute command request.
        System.Threading.Thread objThread = new System.Threading.Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(ExecuteCommandSync));
        //Make the thread as background thread.
        objThread.IsBackground = true;
        //Set the Priority of the thread.
        objThread.Priority = ThreadPriority.AboveNormal;
        //Start the thread.
        objThread.Start(command);
    }
    catch (ThreadStartException objException)
    {
        // Log the exception
    }
    catch (ThreadAbortException objException)
    {
        // Log the exception
    }
    catch (Exception objException)
    {
        // Log the exception
    }
}

string cmdStr = @" ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat""
                  cd ""C:\Users\Johan\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\CCOSApp""
                  msbuild /target:Build /p:BuildingProject=true;OutDir=C:\Temp\build 
                  ccosapp.sln";
ExecuteCommandAsync(cmdStr);
```

Comment: Did you escape the path in your command with quotation marks?

Comment: @Sidewinder94 what do you mean

Comment: Your code runs fine here. The `"` do their job.

Comment: But why do I get that "error" message in CMD

Comment: What I meant was that you should prepent a `"` in your command string and append one so that the text in command would be treated as a single argument.

Comment: You see a message because in the path `C:\Program Files\...` there is a space. If the path is not enclosed in quotes, the cmd, will think that `C:\Program` is the program you want to run while `Files\...` is an argument

Comment: But that's exactly what I do. Look at the value of cmdStr.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is creating a .bat file, opening cmd.exe in code and locating the .bat file.

Comment: Just a guess but I think the problem was you can't pass multiple commands like you did. try putting a `&` between the commands to chain them together using your old way and try getting rid of the newlines.